# Microsoft Auth provider with graphClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

I have an application which uses Microsoft auth provider. I want to initiate GraphServiceClient after I log in with the azure ad user. When I examine the User.Identity object I can find no data that would resemble some kind of an access token. All I can see is my name and Claims.

What's the correct way to initiate GraphServiceClient after logging in with the MSA provider ? Is my question even correct ? Do I need to initialize GraphServiceClient or it's already initialized for me ? Do you have some examples?

I tried all the examples that are on msdn and also hack-together github repo. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `"I tried all the examples that are on msdn and also hack-together github repo. Nothing seems to work"` could you please include the way you have tried? Which github repo you have gone through? What issue you had encountered?